# Is there a way to break/return from Vue3 `<script setup>`?

Tags: vuejs3, vue-script-setup

Is there a way to break/return from Vue3 `<script setup>`?

```html
<script setup lang="ts">
  // code is not working, for illustration purpose
  if (!process.client) return

  // do something...
  const count = ref(0)
</script>
```

Comment: I think we need more context to understand why you would like to do this. I see one major problem already, the `count` var will not be defined in the template part and this will create an error

Comment: Not enough context to offer proper answer. What should happen with the component if condition isn't met? Should it still be mounted, but all scripts disabled, should it unmount?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used `<ClientOnly>` tag in nuxt 3 recently, when I needed to hide a logic from ssr. Maybe this idea will help you somehow

```
<ClientOnly>
  <ComplexComponentWithLogic />
</ClientOnly>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script setup lang="ts">
function load() {
    if (!process.client) {
        // router.push('/')
        return;
    }
}
load();

const count = ref(0);
</script>
```